# the efficiency of MYSQL COUNT query

Tags: mysql

so I executed this query on a table:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

and the 'rows' column from the output is displayed as NULL (whereas usually it will show how many rows the query went through)...

does this mean that the COUNT command is instantaneous and therefore does not require going through any row whatsoever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table uses the `MyISAM` storage engine, then yes, that query resolves in constant time. The row count is part of the table metadata, the table itself does not have to be examined.

Comment: Then it'll probably use the primary key index. The row count is not stored separately for `InnoDB` tables. The `EXPLAIN` would tell you this. For `MyISAM` it'll say `Select tables optimized away`, for `InnoDB` it'll tell you what index, if any, is used.

Answer (score 0):

Many database engines use an [index scan](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL#COUNT.28.2A.29) to get the count.  If you're using MyISAM (fairly likely), it just reads a number in the engine index and returns it.  Nearly instantaneous.

### Edit:

[InnoDB does a full table scan](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/), so it will almost always be slower (than an engine that uses the table index), unless you're comparing queries with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The page you link contradicts what you said. InnoDB is not the same way, whether there is a `WHERE` clause or not. I think you've misread.

Comment: @Dan, you're right.  It was very late when I answered this question :)  I've fixed the error in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL#COUNT.28.2A.29

Depending on what engine you are using, and I'm guessing it's MyISAM, a quick index count is executed rather than actually counting all the rows.